# Relation XX does not exist; could not extract Resultset error while using a view convertHibernateAccessException

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, sql-view

I am using a view in my entity class. Although the view-column mappings are exactly the same as in  entity class, I am receiving the exception "ERROR: relation "location_view" does not exist - Position: 15 - underlying exception is SQLGrammarException could not extract ResultSet at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)"

When I replace the view to the underlying SQL query, it works in SpringBoot. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "location_view")
public class Location{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    long id;
  
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "total")
    long total;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    long createdBy;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    Timestamp createdOn;
}

public interface LocationDAO extends JpaRepository<Location, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from location_view", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Location> getLocations();
}
```

In my controller, I am making call to locationDAO.getLocations();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the table/view is in a different schema? Or maybe the user for the JDBC connection has no permission to read from that table/view?